# Configuring View output with multiple related nodes

Tags: views

Real world: Our not-for-profit holds monthly meetings. At each meeting, zero, one, or two people can present.

My site has:

- Content type Presenter with fields Name and Description
- Content type Meeting with field Date, Topic, and Node Reference (which will allow a maximum of two entries)

I created a View to show the meeting information. What I would like to see is this:

```
Meeting Date
Meeting Topic
Presenter 1 Name
Presenter 1 Description
Presenter 2 Name
Presenter 2 Description
```

What I am currently seeing is this:

```
Meeting Date
Meeting Topic
Presenter 1 Name
Presenter 1 Description
Meeting Date
Meeting Topic
Presenter 2 Name
Presenter 2 Description
```

I have tried several things to fixed this: Grouping, SQL Distinct (via Advanced->Other->Query Settings), and others, but so far, nothing has worked. This seems like something which should be easy to do - but I have yet to find the proper incantation.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried grouping by the node id (the same node id used in the node reference)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply but how do I even add a GROUP BY clause to my query? Thanks!

Comment: Desmond - thanks for the reply. Two responses for clarification:

Comment: Desmond - thanks for the reply. I tried the following:
First attempt:
1 - Added the Node ID for the content type Meeting to the list of fields
2 – Under Format->Setting->Group By, used this NID for grouping
Second attempt:
1 - Added the Node ID for the content type Presenter (via the relationship) to the list of fields
2 – Under Format->Setting->Group By, used this NID for grouping
Neither approach worked – did I misunderstand your suggestion?